# What's the different between _id and _uid in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Well, here is the detail:

First, I create three documents:

```
foo/bar/1
foo/bar/2
foo/bar/3
```

I want to get max id:

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  host: 'localhost: 9200'
});

client.search({
  index: 'foo',
  type: 'bar',
  sort: '_id:desc',
  size: 1,
  fields: [ '_id' ]
}, function(err, resp) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  console.log(resp.hits); // _id is '1'
})
```

In the code above, I can not get right result.

Then, I google the reason about it, I found the '_uid'

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  host: 'localhost: 9200'
});

client.search({
  index: 'foo',
  type: 'bar',
  sort: '_uid:desc', // here is a little bit different
  size: 1,
  fields: [ '_id' ]
}, function(err, resp) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  console.log(resp.hits); // _id is '3'
})
```

Yes I get the right result.

So question is

**Can I say '_id' and '_uid' are the same things?**

**Is '_id' equal to '_uid'?**

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly same .

The `_uid` field is automatically used when `_type` is not indexed to perform type based filtering, and does not require the `_id` to be indexed.

http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/mapping-uid-field.html

Answer (score 1):

No they are not the same. *_uid* is a combination of the type and *_id*: *{type}#{id}*. As a result *_uid* is unique inside an index, whereas *_id* is unique inside a type ([see the official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-uid-field.html)).

Comment: Update : `_uid` is deprecated . https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/breaking-changes-7.0.html#uid-meta-field-removed